# belongsTo–hasOne relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make a relationship in Laravel and when I use a `hasOne` relation it returns null.

The table format is like this:

```
┌─────────┐   ┌─────────────────┐   ┌───────────────┐
│ socio   │ ← │ socioGf         │ → │ grupoFamiliar │
├─────────┤   ├─────────────────┤   ├───────────────┤
│ id      │   │ idSocio         │   │ id            │
│         │   │ idGrupoFamiliar │   │               │
└─────────┘   └─────────────────┘   └───────────────┘
```

Here's my code:

Model `SocioGf`:

```
...
public function grupoFamiliar(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\GrupoFamiliar','id','idGrupoFamiliar')
     ->toSql();
}
public function socio(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\Socio','id','idSocio');
}
...
```

Model `socio`:

```
...
public function socioGf(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SocioGf', 'idSocio', 'id');
}  
...
```

Model `grupoFamiliar`:

```
...
public function socioGf(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SocioGf', 'idGrupoFamiliar','id');
} 
...
```

In my `grupoFamiliarController` I return:

```
$gruposFamiliares = GrupoFamiliar::paginate($this->paginateNumber);        
return view('gruposFamiliares',compact('gruposFamiliares'));
```

So in the `gruposFamiliares.blade.php` I try to access this way:

```
@forelse($gruposFamiliares as $grupoFamiliar)
    {{dd($grupoFamiliar->socioGf)}}
    @foreach($grupoFamiliar->socioGf() as $gf)
        {{dd($gf->socio)}}
    @endforeach
@endforelse
```

In the second line the `dd` shows a null variable, any idea why?

Comment: In the hasOne relationship, the model that "belongs" is the one that must keep the foreign keys.  It seems that you have it invested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the relation [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

In model `socio`:

```
...
public function gruposFamiliares(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(GrupoFamiliar::class, 'socioGf_table', 'socioId', 'grupoFamiliarId');
}
...
```

In model `grupoFamiliar`:

```
...
public function socios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Socio::class, 'socioGf_table', 'grupoFamiliarId', 'socioId');
}
...
```

Then you can access `socios` and `gruposFamiliares` like this:

```
$socio->gruposFamiliares()->get();
$grupoFamiliar->socios()->get();
```

Each of these lines will return a collection of Socios and GruposFamiliares.